# Neural networks for an imbalanced dataset

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a very imbalanced dataset consisting of 186219 rows of data by 6 dimensions including 132 true positives against 186087 false positives, what types of neural network would you recommend to try? This spreadsheet in my google drive [IPDC_algorithm_training_dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oT8jZYof-_8CiHsL5yroMjIOhsVNlkHu) contains my training dataset. If the value in output tab has a value of 100, that feature is a true positive, and if a feature has a value of 0 means that feature is a false positive.

I am tied up with MATLAB now, so it would be more convenient for me if I use MATLAB for this problem.

Comment: Question should be tagged `matlab` (added), while it has nothing to do with `svm` or `libsvm` (removed).

Comment: You may be better off doing anomaly detection.

Answer (score 0):

With a dataset that imbalanced you have limited options.  If you trained a neural network on the entire dataset, it'd achieve 99.9% accuracy just by always predicting false positives.  You need to deal with that imbalance in some way, such as discarding (vast swathes of) false positive samples or weighting your loss function to account for the imbalance.  With an imbalance as extreme as this, you'd probably need to apply both (along with regularisation to prevent overfitting the remaining data).

In terms of what network type to use, you could try just a basic MLP (Multi-Layer Perceptron), at least as a baseline – there's no point in building a complicated architecture, with more parameters to train, with a very limited dataset.

In reality, you'd probably be better off using a shallow learning algorithm, such as boosted trees or naive Bayes, or getting more data to enable use of a neural network.  If new data is likely to remain as imbalanced, you'd need a very large amount of extra data.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have been using boosted binary regression trees (BBRT), but the results are not that good that I want. I found the weighted SVM for extremely imbalanced cases, but the codes do not work  I just started playing with SVM.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45924-weighted-support-vector-machines